# Show all the records instead of recently viewed records

Tags: lookup-filter, recentlyviewed

On Clicking Look up field,it will show recently viewed records.But is it possible to show all the records which are satisfying the filter criteria,instead of showing recently viewed records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible,checked the Ideas on salesforce and it is not delivered.

There you go: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxgoAAA

Comment: Include the link to the Idea Exchange so if people are interested they can upvote the idea.